# Send Message to selected user using laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to send message to selected user  unfortunately I am facing error how to fix it ? thanks.

please check error 
  https://flareapp.io/share/67OAAVmr#F59

**controller**

```
                public function chataction(REQUEST $request)
                {   
                $user = Auth::user();
                $m = $user->Chats()->create([             
               'chat_message' => $request->input('message'),
               'from_user_id' =>Auth::user()->id,
               'to_user_id' =>$request->input('id'),
               ]);          
               return ['status' => 'Message Sent!'];
                }
```

**html view**

```
          <form action="{{route('chat.action')}}" method="post">
          @csrf
          <input type="hidden" name="id" >
          <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" id="chatmessage" name="message" placeholder="Type Message ..." 
          class="form-control">
          <span class="input-group-append">
          <button type="submit" name="btnsubmit" id="btnsubmit"  class="btn btn- 
          primary">Send</button>
          </span>
          </div>
          </form>
```

Comment: Make sure the field `from_user_id` is fillable in your Chat model

Comment: Not only `from_user_id` but also `chat_message` should be fillable in you Chat model (I can see that it's not).

Answer (score 2):

**Change your REQUEST**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function chataction(Request $request)
   {   
     $user = Auth::user();
     $m = $user->Chats()->create([             
          'chat_message' => $request->input('message'),
          'from_user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
          'to_user_id' => $request->input('id'),
          ]);          
         return ['status' => 'Message Sent!'];
   }
```

**Change In your Model**

*use `fillable` when you are use `create` method to **insert** data*

```
protected $fillable = ['chat_message', 'from_user_id', 'to_user_id'];
```

Comment: please select this answer if its help for you !! Thank You @Zubair

Comment: please chack  https://ibb.co/GCMjvz7  from_user_id and to_user_id should not be same because i am sending message to  selected users thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1 - Modify your `App\Chat` model so `$fillable` looks like this:

```
protected $fillable = ['chat_message', 'from_user_id', 'to_user_id'];
```

2 - Modify your controller to use `Illuminate\Http\Request` and change your method argument's capitalisation from `REQUEST` to `Request`.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function chataction(Request $request)
{
     ...
}
```

---

To answer your question in comments,

This is what your method should look like this:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function chataction(Request $request)
{   
 $user = Auth::user();

 if($request->id == $user->id){
     return response("Can't message yourself!");
 }

 $m = $user->Chats()->create([             
      'chat_message' => $request->input('message'),
      'from_user_id' => $user->id,
      'to_user_id' => $request->input('id'),
      ]);     

  return ['status' => 'Message Sent!'];
}
```

**Note:** Please update your question to include your query regarding comparison between `from_user_id` and `to_user_id` for the benefit of future visitors.

Comment: i am login from_user_id 14  and than sending message user_id 13 but  inside database, from_user_id and to_user_id same but   should not be same because i have to send messag selected user how can i resolve this user ?

Comment: You can validate that at the beginning of your method. Something like this:
`if($request->id == Auth::user()->id){ return response("Can't message yourself"); }`

Comment: Another approach would be to exclude `Auth::user()` from the list of contacts you are providing the user to message.